# Is there a way to customize the tool tip ellipsis feature in dataTables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, css-selectors

Is there a way to customize the tool tip ellipsis feature (plug-in) in jQuery Data Tables?
I tried modifying the tooltip text in my css file but it does not do anything.
documentation: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/ellipsis

```
ellipsis.tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: To override the particular CSS property , you can use !important .

Comment: Nice idea. I might try that actually

Comment: edit: it does not help. I tried adding !important after every property and it still doesn't do much.